# Retracted a flag and asked for moderator intervention

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, moderator-intervention

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60615568/flutter-upload-pdf-to-google-drive) and at first I figured the user just had weird wording and wanted some help setting the API access up.

The user replied that he wanted a tutorial instead, making this question closeable, not due to it being a duplicate, but due to it requesting an off-site resource.

Since I retracted a flag, I could not raise the correct one again, and asked for moderator intervention:

[image: The response from my flag]

What should have happened instead?

Comment: You cannot flag for closure a second time, so you'll have to defer it to those who still can, instead of flagging for moderator intervention.

Comment: Adding to ^^ There is the Stack Overflow Close-Vote chatroom where one can go to bring things that should be closed to the attention of the community. Be sure to read their FAQ rules before posting, however.

Comment: This didn't require moderator intervention; merely the intervention of other community members.

Comment: Hmm. I'm sympathetic here. As long as you explain *in the flag* why you needed to flag for moderator attention and could not have taken the action yourself, I'd be inclined to review the situation and decide whether or not I agree that action needs to be taken, rather than just dismiss the flag out of hand for procedural reasons. I guess moderator opinions vary on this. If you don't like playing Russian roulette against the mod team, you might be interested in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers); please read [their FAQ](https://socvr.org/).